# How to add javax.swing.SwingUtilities dependency to SBT?

Tags: swing, scala, sbt

I'm starting to develop a Scala application with Swing using SBT. I figured out that I need two dependencies for a start, so that's scala-swing and javax.swing.SwingUtilities.
I've been searching the web, maven repositories and github, but stil couldn't find, where did the javax.swing package go.
So far I have found javax in Maven Repos, but javax.swing is not listed there for some reason.

I tried to add a javax dependency to my Build.scala:

```
val javax = "javax" % "javaee-api" % "7.0"
```

SBT downloaded several packages. Then I launched the terminal:

```
scala> import javax.swing.SwingUtilities
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities

scala> SwingUtilities.invokeLater()
<console>:9: error: not enough arguments for method invokeLater: (x$1: Runnable)Unit.
Unspecified value parameter x$1.
              SwingUtilities.invokeLater()
                                        ^
```

That's scala console being launched from sbt project. So as you can see, import was successful and the console knows about invokeLater() method. But IntelliJ Idea still does not, it marks javax.swing as unresolvable, though it has downloaded the packages.
I'm completely stuck here.

Comment: SwingUtilities.invokeLater() is part of the scala library and called onEDT, try

  import scala.swing._
  Swing.onEDT( println("hello") )

Comment: So it's doesn't matter whether I use SwingUtilities.invokeLater() or Swing.onEDT(), it only matters that I execute code in a separate thread? Does that mean that I can actually implement my own Event Dispatcher and use it with Swing?

Comment: almost, There is only one Swing Event Dispatcher thread and both methods allow you to execute code on that thread. Swing.onEDT is just a cleaner way of doing this. Think as if Swing is single threaded and this a way to add a task for it to perform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`javax.swing` is part of any standard Java SE installation (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/ - there you have `SwingUtilities`), so there is no need to add a dependency. You only need the scala-swing dependency:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-swing" % scalaVersion.value
```

If IntelliJ IDEA doesn't see `javax.swing`, you have probably not yet defined an "SDK". Go to File -> Project Structure -> Platform Settings -> SDKs. There you should have at least one entry such as "1.6" for Java 1.6 or "1.7" for Java 1.7. If not, press the "+" to add one and locate the appropriate Java home directory for the version you want to use (depends on your OS).

[image]